# Reading a parameter and submitting form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Background:** 
I have two tables lunches and comments. The two tables use different controllers and have different views.  The two views are also connected with lunches (one) to comments (many) relationship.

I am passing a lunch_id from *lunches/index.html.erb* to *comments/new* with

```
<%= button_to 'Comment', new_comment_path(lunch_id: lunch) %>
```

I know the passing works because the comments/new url string contains the lunch_id: http://localhost:3000/comments/new?lunch_id=1

The *comments/new* is a scaffolded form that creates comments and accepts the params below in the controller:

```
params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :lunch_id)
```

Currently, the user has to type in the body and the lunch_id into the form. Then, the comments_controller uses the create method below

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
end
```

**Question:** 
In the create method of the comments_controller (above), how do I read the :lunch_id from the url string and combine it with the user entered :body to create the new comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will take the param from the url and add it to the comment record.

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  @comment.update_attribute(:lunch_id, params[:lunch_id])
  @comment.save
end
```

Comment: Tried it, for some reason params[:lunch_id] comes back as blank so it doesn't assign a lunch_id, even though the url string is: "http://localhost:3000/comments/new?lunch_id=1/"  Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Odd, it may have something to do with comment_params. Try adding `lunch_id = params[:lunch_id]` at the top of the method and then replace `params[:lunch_id]` with `lunch_id`. (I don't know if strong parameters modifies the params hash.)

Comment: You know what, the problem was <%= button_to 'Comment', new_comment_path(lunch_id: lunch) %> was a post request in the routes.rb.. Any ideas on why the lunch_id shows up in the url string on a post request, I though those are only on get requests?

Comment: POST requests can have URL params.